# Sim card failed

Tags: cyanogenmod, sim-card

Ever since that I got the cyanogen 7 it says that no SIM -- but it is in there. I was wondering how to solve the problem It has been ... quite and adventure.

**What I've tried:**

First I tried Heimdall from Ubuntu (didn't even connect to the phone). Then I tried from Windows, using its graphical interface. It had the "repartition" flag activated by default, when it shouldn't, so I bricked my phone.

After lots of trial an error, I managed to install a ROM in my phone, using Odin as root, the stock cable, and a different USB port than the one I was using (go figure...). And from there I was able to install cyanogenmod as it says on the instructions. Then I had to reinstall them, because they were bootlooping.

END TL;DR

**Current Status:**

So, now I've got a Samsung Galaxy S with Cyanogenmod 7. But it complaints that it doesn't detect any SIM card. When it boots up, it says `No SIM card. Emergency calls only`. Notice that it doesn't say "incompatible SIM", nor it asks me for a password of any kind. It just doesn't seem to detect the card at all.

**Question:**

What steps can I follow to solve this issue, or at least get more information about it?

Comment: Since you soft-bricked your phone I would ask to test a stock ROM and see if the SIM fails or it works as intended. If the SIM fails, it might be something of your phone, not the ROM.

Comment: Find the appropriate PIT file for your device and flash the original, signed, stock OS via Odin with re-partition checked and that PIT selected.  Then see if the SIM card works on that firmware.

Comment: Have you tried reseating the SIM card or cleaning its contacts with rubbing alcohol? Does your SIM card function correctly in a known-working phone? Sometimes it's the silly things.

Answer (score 1):

SIM card interface is connected to the Baseband processor. The error message you are seeing most likely means that during conversion to Cyanogen you have erased and/or reflashed BP image. The easiest way to reverse is to go back to the stock software. After telephony is functional again - you should ask for help with the proper Cyanogen installation procedure for your device.